# How to write number of characters of a string in a textfield?

Tags: javascript, string

Okay, I have this textfield form that contains some text.
What I need to do is to count number of characters of that particular string and print it into another textfield form, basically like this:

```
function numberOfCharacters() {

    var number = document.forms[0].textfield1.length;
    document.forms[0].textfield2.value = number;

}
```

When I do this, textfield2 contains "undefined" string.
Thank you

Comment: don't use `document.forms` to find elements, give your element a unique id and use `document.getElementById('myId');`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
...textfield1.**value**.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#text-input').bind('keyup', function() {
   $('#char-count-ouptput').val($(this).val().length);
});
```